# Forge / Trigger.io cannot find adb even

Tags: android, trigger.io, forge

Trying to run forge run android command and getting this error even though file is present (Ubuntu 12.04). Even if I do not specify the sdk path and allow forge to download it on its own, I am still getting the same error.

```
2012-07-04 15:08:36,414 [  DEBUG] Exception running detached command:
/home/rockyj/Apps/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory while running
run_android(('/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/development',
u'/home/rockyj/Apps/android-sdk-linux', None, True, None), {})
2012-07-04 15:08:36,417 [  ERROR] Something went wrong that we didn't expect:
2012-07-04 15:08:36,417 [  ERROR] Exception running detached command:
/home/rockyj/Apps/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
2012-07-04 15:08:36,417 [  DEBUG] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rockyj/Apps/forge-tools/forge/async.py", line 87, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/rockyj/Apps/forge-tools/forge/main.py", line 388, in run
    build_to_run=build_to_run,
  File "/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/.template/generate_dynamic/customer_goals.py",
line 120, in run_app
    build_to_run.run()
  File "/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py",
line 338, in run
    self._run_task(func_name, args, kw)
  File "/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/.template/generate_dynamic/build.py",
line 293, in _run_task
    self.tasks[func_name](self, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/.template/generate_dynamic/android_tasks.py",
line 588, in run_android
    run_detached([path_info.adb, 'start-server'], wait=True)
  File "/home/rockyj/Workspace/Projects/greeter/.template/generate_dynamic/android_tasks.py",
line 377, in run_detached
    raise ShellError(message="Exception running detached command: %s"
% full_command, output=str(output))
ShellError: Exception running detached command:
/home/rockyj/Apps/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect this is a case of just needing to apt-get install ia32-libs, but it might be easier to exchange information over email, could you please contact us at support@trigger.io ?

Comment: Thanks it worked! My mistake, should have looked at this  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, this issue was fixed by installing ia32 libs on Ubuntu.